# How to bind to and use a higher-order component in ReasonReact

Tags: interop, higher-order-components, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

Let's say I have a higher-order component, something like the following trivial definition, exported from the JavaScript module `./hoc.js`:

```js
export const withStrong =
  Component => props =>
    <strong> <Component ...props/> </strong>
```

Assuming I have some component called `HelloMessage`, what is the equivalent of this piece of JavaScript:

```js
import { withStrong } from './hoc.js';

const HelloMessage = ...

const StrongMessage = withStrong(HelloMessage);

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrongMessage name="Joe" />,
  document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

This should be the exact equivalent of the requested JavaScript snippet:

```rust
[@bs.module ./hoc.js]
external withStrong
  : React.component('props) => React.component('props)
  = "withStrong";

module HelloMessage = ...

module StrongMessage = {
  include HelloMessage;
  let make = withStrong(make);
};

ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(
  <StrongMessage name="Joe" />,
  "react-app"
);
```

There'a also [a runnable example on the Reason playground](https://reasonml.github.io/try?rrjsx=true&reason=NoAQRgzgdAxg9gOwGYEsDmACA3gKwgDwC4MBmAXwF0BuAKBuAFIGAnAQwHdsAfG+BCAC4Z2KAQAsAygOaJMAXhoYMAIVYQApgGE4AWwAOidQiFyAfBj0y9EDGcVKMAJXWsYA2MxcD1AUQA26jpGAgAUAESCMghoYQA0GAgArn5+sfYOTi5uHl6+AUHGIaoa2vqGxvGWcNYAlDU0XJR0oJBQAG6sfhQ06vjezAidwqKS0rL2xM6u7vBlCMEhAOSsNbbmU9mzBvOFy-VKchhhIuJSUTG0NDpwACbJ6hgAEuopcACy6hAQrGgPh1j2UCeaawXTbYLdJQBIQ6VgAaz+GBCAD9BkFVnYMgAeG4oNrmLAbdyRFDRcLPV5HDAAampCVY6LIGCxAHpcfiaGRLtc7gEMGdZB8vj9EQClCyAFQYFrQOBgHAUDC9fqDPwYWEIgAKVggxBRaPUxEWBrkAH54okEKIMQSoEcDWEjQamYcwmEqBgJSz7KSYH5EjcHhS-O9Pt9frQlPZoer4YiTqNziFg6Hhb8oBr1DVaGQ6ESACIAeTezigngQgeYABU4P5AsEAOojACSNxC9hxeNM9gAkFiU0Lww8TWEAFJwdRhDAs7vYgXRQci+lBORhedoMCsG4AQinM47bK7aSUYUs6jaKHU7DCNGzQA) with a few adaptations made to work around not having a separate JavaScript file.

Explanation follows:

### Binding

`withStrong` is just a function. It happens to be a function that accepts and returns a react component, which is a bit mysterious, but they're really just values like any other. We can just bind it like an ordinary function.

Even something as simple as this would work

```ml
[@bs.module ./hoc.js]
external withStrong : 'a => 'a = "withStrong";
```

assuming you always make sure to pass in a component. But it wouldn't be particularly safe as you can pass it anything else too, so let's try to use the type system as it should be used, restricting it to only accept react components.

The [ReasonReact source code](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/master/src/React.re) says components have the type `component('props)`, so that's what we'll use.

```ml
[@bs.module ./hoc.js]
external withStrong
  : React.component('props) => React.component('props)
  = "withStrong";
```

Using the `'props` type variable in both the argument and return type means we constrain them to be the same. That is, the returned component will have exactly the same props as the one passed in, which is exactly what we want in this case.

And that's really all there is to the binding itself. we can now use it like this:

```ml
let strongMessage = withStrong(HelloMessage.make);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't support JSX. To render `strongMessage` as is we'd have to write something like

```rust
React.createElementVariadic(strongMessage, { "name": "Joe" }, [||]);
```

Not great. So let's fix that.

### JSX

```js
<StrongMessage name="Joe" />
```

[transforms](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/jsx#capitalized) to

```rust
React.createElementVariadic(
  StrongMessage.make,
  StrongMessage.makeProps(~name="Joe", ()),
  [||]
);
```

So we need a `StrongMessage` module with two functions, `make` and `makeProps` that conform to what's expected by `React.createElementVariadic`. `make` is just the component itself, so that's simple enough. `makeProps` is a function that acccepts the props as labeled arguments terminated by `unit` (since the props may be optional) and returns a js object. This also happens to be exactly what [`[@bs.obj]`](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object-2#function) does, which isn't in any way coincidental.

Putting this together then, we get:

```rust
module StrongMessage = {
  let make = withStrong(HelloMessage.make);

  [@bs.obj]
  external makeProps
    : (~name: string, unit) => {. "name" string }
    = "";
}
```

And that's it! Yay!

**Addendum: Shortcuts**

Ok, so the `makeProps` function is a bit of an annoying mouthful. Fortunately in our case, where the props of the wrapped component is the same as the original, it's also unnecessary since `StrongMessage.makeProps` will be identical to `HelloMessage.makeProps`. Let's just steal that then! And now we have

```rust
module StrongMessage = {
  let make = withStrong(HelloMessage.make);
  let makeProps = HelloMessage.makeProps;
}
```

But we can do even better! By using `include HelloMessage` we can drop `makeProps` entirely (thanks to @bloodyowl, via @idkjs, for this one).

```rust
module StrongMessage = {
  include HelloMessage;
  let make = withStrong(make);
}
```

That's pretty nice, isn't it? This works because `include HelloMessage` will include all the exported definitions from `HelloMessage` such as `makeProps`, but also `make` and anything else. This is probably what you want when you wrap a component in this way, but beware that it imports and re-exports *everything* from the included module, in case that's *not* what you want.

### Usage

Finally, once we have both the binding and JSX in order we can use it like this

```rust
ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(
  <StrongMessage name="Joe" />,
  "react-app"
);
```

Comment: HI @glennsl, what does this look like if your HOC is returning something with the component, like authstate? Or put another way, how do I access the props that come back with the component? Thank you.

Comment: @idkjs I'm not sure what you mean. Can you point me to an example in JavaScript?

Comment: @glennsl how can we handle a case where a hoc returns a component which can accept an extra prop? 
eg: a styled hoc which accepts a component and returns a component which will accept a new prop called css

Comment: @a-c-sreedhar-reddy As far as I know there`s unfortunately no way to extend a props type with extra props.